# Iellegible JFET name, seems to be HEPxxxxx

Tags: transistors, semiconductors, jfet, fet, p-channel

I have this poor scanned schematic on which there is a Motorola P-channel JFET, labeled as Q5, and I can't read the name. It seems to me that the 2nd note is written "Q5 is HEP*1036" where * represents an unknown character. So, does anyone know what it could be? Is there a HEPxxxx series of JFET's?

On this other datasheet there is the same circuit using the 2N5461, but I can't find those down here in Brazil.
https://datasheetspdf.com/datasheet/MC1315P.html

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: [It seems that NTE](https://www.weisd.com/products/834145-hep801-nte-equivalent-nte312-jfet-n-channel-30v-to) made (or makes)  JFETs with HEPXXXX  designations.

Comment: Right, Andrew Morton, thank you and just added the full circuit, and also a reprint on the datasheet with a legible note sugesting the 2N5461, which I can't buy from local suppliers.

Comment: For an obsolete part, 2N5461 and the SMT version MMBF5461 seem to be reasonably available (eg. eBay,  the usual scumbags who sell obsolete parts etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a HEP F1036

An internet search for `cbc motorola sq decoder` finds this.

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cbs+motorola+sq+decoder&iax=images&ia=images

[image]

https://www.ka-electronics.com/images/jpg/CBS_SQ_Decoder_Variable_Blend_small.JPG

Comment: NTE rebadged from whoever the *real* manufacturer might be, appears to be [NTE460](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/464365/NTE/NTE460/1), in TO-72 metal case.

Comment: Thank you so much, I looked for MC1315, MC1314 and all I could find was this poorly scanned pint and legible print with the 2N5461.